# Implementing controlled rotation for FRQI by using controlled Ry and NOT Gate

Tags: qiskit, circuit-construction, gate-synthesis

I was reading about Flexible Representation of Quantum Images (FRQI) encoding in [Qiskit textbook](https://qiskit.org/textbook/ch-applications/image-processing-frqi-neqr.html). It says that, given $$\{\theta_0, \theta_1, ..., \theta_{4^{n}-1}\}  \quad  (\theta_i \in [0,\pi/2])$$ we can transform $\mid{0}\rangle^{\otimes2n+1}$ into FRQI state $\mid{I(\theta)}\rangle$ by applying unitary operator $\mathcal{R}\mathcal{H}$, with $\mathcal{H}= I \otimes H^{\otimes 2n}$ and $\mathcal{R}= \prod_{i=0}^{4^n-1}R_i$. where $$\mid{I(\theta)}\rangle= \frac{1}{2^n}\sum_{i=0}^{4^n-1}(cos \theta_i|{0}\rangle+sin \theta_i|{1}\rangle)\otimes |{i}\rangle$$

And $R_i$ is a unitary matrix named **controlled rotation**, given by
$$R_i= I \otimes \sum_{j=0, j \neq i}^{4^n-1} |{j}\rangle \langle {j}| + R_y(2\theta_i) \otimes  |{i}\rangle \langle {i}\mid$$
I would like to implement the controlled rotation $R_i$ or $\mathcal{R}$ using $C^{2n}R_y$ (controlled $R_y$) and $X$ gate.

**Edit:** I think I have made some progress. We can write,
$$ R_i= I^{\otimes 2n+1}+(R_y(2\theta_i)-I) \otimes  |{i}\rangle \langle {i}\mid$$
$$ C^{2n}R_y(2\theta_i)= I^{\otimes 2n+1}+(R_y(2\theta_i)-I) \otimes  |{4^n-1}\rangle \langle {4^n-1}\mid $$
Please review my results and suggest me how to approach further.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have controlled$^{2n}-R_Y$, this is fairly straightforward. This means that what you already have is
$$
C^{2n} R_y(2\theta_i)=I^{\otimes(2n+1)}+(R_Y(2\theta_i)-I)\otimes |1\rangle\langle 1|^{\otimes 2n}
$$
and you are aiming to make
$$
R_i=I^{\otimes(2n+1)}+(R_Y(2\theta_i)-I)\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|.
$$
Now, let $X_x$ be a tensor product of Pauli $X$ matrices that have the action
$$
X_x|i\rangle=|1\rangle^{\otimes 2n}\rangle.
$$
In other words, if $y$ is the binary representation of $i$, then
$$
x=y\oplus 11\ldots 1=\bar y.
$$
Then
\begin{align*}
X_x C^{2n} R_y(2\theta_i)X_x&=X_x(I^{\otimes(2n+1)}+(R_Y(2\theta_i)-I)\otimes |1\rangle\langle 1|^{\otimes 2n})X_x\\
&=I^{\otimes(2n+1)}+(R_Y(2\theta_i)-I)\otimes |i\rangle\langle i|\\
&=R_i.
\end{align*}